# jQuery event in JavaScript object error on apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, object

I don't really understand how to set listeners in my JavaScript object.
For example:

```
var obj = function(){

    this.test = function(){
        console.log('test');
    }

    $(document).on('click','#test',(function(){
        this.test();
    }).bind(this));
}
```

But jQuery gives me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #test has no method 'apply'
```

I think there is a proper way but I can't find.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
I don't know really why it works in my example but not in my code

http://jsfiddle.net/nhJNH/

Comment: Reproduce it on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. The only error in that code is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }", but when I [fix that and instantiate an instance of the class so the function actually runs](http://jsbin.com/aribuv/1/edit), the code works as I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var obj = function(){

    this.test = function(){
        console.log('test');
    }
    var t = this;

    $(document).on('click','#test', function(){
        t.test();
    });

}
```

You may also use

```
$(document).on('click','#test', $.proxy(this.test, this));
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#test', $.proxy(function () {
    this.test();
}, this));
```